# React Router v4 not working even with exact path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import AutoSuggestContainer from 'containers/AutoSuggest'

export default class MeksiRouter extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
                <Router> 
                    <Switch> 
                        <Route exact path='/ai' component={AutoSuggestContainer}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            )
    }
}
```

- React Router v4 not working even with exact path , can anyone help me please

Comment: Please put more detail to your question. And what situation does this occur? Did you receive an error?

Comment: Can you post the error message you get if any?

Comment: the console doesn't show any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a provided very little context of your problem here. From the existing code, I can point you to two directions on where you might be wrong.

**Case 1:** 
This is not a main router and this is a component inside another page maybe. Where you want to add more routing. If that's the case you forgot this:

```
<Route exact path={`${this.props.match.url}/ai`} component={AutoSuggestContainer}/>
```

**Case 2:**
Your component might be returning empty or null. If it's not the first case. Try creating a component with minimal code like hello world and try to put it there and see if it works Or try to remove the whole router thing and see if that component renders.

I hope this helps, If it doesn't please provide more context of the project.